# Loading document in shared documents folder into WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I am having problems trying to load a document into a WKWebView when the document has been added to the app using iTunes file sharing.

If I include the file inside the app I can load it fine.

I am using this code to get the load the file:

```
let documentsURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let fooURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(docFileName)
let docURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fooURL.path)
let req = URLRequest(url:docURL)
docView!.load(req)
```

docURL looks like this:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/432E716E-F70D-4985-814C-FFE7ECE53EF8/Documents/filename.pdf

I have tried to check the file exists using this code:

```
FileManager().fileExists(atPath: fooURL.path)
```

This returns true. I have also tried to copy the file from the documents folder into the app folder but this returns an error of file not found (again this is even after checking the file exists)

Should WKWebView be able to load from this location? Or have I missed something here?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this problem? If so, can you post an answer with what you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessTo:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl)

Though I didn't see it explicitly stated in the docs, it wouldn't surprise me if the security policies of WKWebView are getting in your way, and the presence of this method alone seems to confirm that ;-)

Happy coding!